# problem with passing custom array to function (c++)

Tags: c++, pointers, operators, operator-precedence

I have an array of type T which I pass as a pointer parameter to a function.
The problem is that I can't write new data to this array properly, without getting memory violation at the second try.

In this code I read integers from a text file and pass them to the function (part of template class of type T), in order to append them to the array.

After I finish to append the integers, I want to use the same array back in the Main.

Does someone know what's wrong with the code?

Thanks, Max

```
template<class T> int CFile<T>::read(T **apBuf, int aNum)
{
int readCounter = 0;

*apBuf = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T)*aNum);


for (int i = 0; i<aNum; i++)
{
    T var = read();

    if (var == NULL)
    {
        if (isEof)
        {

            return readCounter;
        }
        else
        {
            perror ("Error Reading File - Insufficient var type");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {   
        *apBuf[i] = var;

        readCounter++;
    }
}



return readCounter;

}
```

Comment: Could you flesh out the problem a bit more? Where, precisely, is it failing? What does `read()` (with no parameters) do?

Comment: The parameterless read() is reading T member from a text file, one at a time.
My problem was solved, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*apBuf[i] = var;
```

This is parsed as if it was written:

```
*(apBuf[i]) = var;
```

This is obviously not what you want; `apBuf` is a pointer to a pointer to an array; you are treating it as a pointer to an array and you are dereferencing the `i`th element of it.  What you really mean is:

```
(*apBuf)[i] = var;
```

`*apBuf` gives you "the object pointed to by `apBuf`," which is the array; then you obtain the `i`th element of the array.

That said, this is rather unusual:  why not accumulate the data into a `std::vector<T>` and return that from the function?  Then you don't have to worry about the explicit dynamic memory management.  (Also, is `T` always a pointer type?  If not, then `var == NULL` makes no sense.)

Comment: Thanks!       Damn, I tried to solve this for hours. What a wonderful place.

Comment: I would prefer to use Vector of course - But I write this program not for myself, but for college task. They give strict rools how to do that.

Comment: It's better to learn the correct way to write the code, write the code correctly, and then argue with your professors (at least, that's what I did, and I learned a whole lot more that way than I would have by blindly following inane rules).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you used `malloc` to allocate the array, and then tried to assign to it. This is undefined behaviour, because you have to construct the objects.

Oh, and you should *really*, *really* consider using self-owning resource classes, because malloc and this style of programming in general is hideously unsafe. What if T's copy constructor throws an exception? Memory leak. Just for example.

Answer (score 0):

One issue you have is your using malloc instead of new.  If T is a class the constructor won't be called.